# Why most of the times stand-up comedians work alone?

Tags: comedy

I have watched many stand-up comedies but I have watched few of them to be called a duet or more.

I think having a partner and doing the silly things and dialogues gain more laughs than when they work alone and play different roles. Because in my opinion people will be stunned more if they see multiple people playing multiple roles.

So why do most of stand-up comedians work alone?

Comment: A lot of stand-up comedians suffer from depression and/or mania. Neither of those are especially conducive to building healthy partnerships

Comment: Would you classify Abbot and Costello as stand up comedians?

Comment: Sometimes they were. For example, in a play in front of live audience, Just like Laurel and Hardy did. These comedian duos were so famous and they liked each other so much that they couldn't think about working alone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about stand-up comedy - not Movies and TV

Comment: @iandotkelly First of all if that's off-topic then its tag shouldn't exist. Second, I searched on per-meta site first to see if that's on-topic or not. And I found it to be on-topic

Comment: Tags existing doesn't make your question on topic.  If you look at the questions using the tag, there are 3 including your question.  One is also closed, one is about Johnny Carson ... a talk show host on The Tonight Show, and something he commonly did on that show.

Comment: "And I found it to be on-topic" ... can I ask where you found it?

Comment: In the UK, _TV comedians_ actually do very often start out in ensembles, groups or pairs, often having met at well-connected institutions like the famous [Footlights Club](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footlights). _Pure_ stand-up comedy is more individual-focused here because it's more organic, more about individuals plucking up the courage to stand up at a comedy club's open mic night, then slowly building up a reputation. I guess other countries have something similar, where established comedy cliques have TV connections, while outsides have to slog through the stand-up club circuit?

Comment: @EtackSxchange I'm sure you could make it unambiguously on-topic if you tweak it to be like "Why are stand-up comedians so often solo shows when TV comedians almost never do?" and compare stand-up comedy to things like for-TV formats like sketch shows and panel shows that feature very similar jokes and often similar performers, but are almost never solo shows

Answer (score 2):

One major advantage of being a solo act in live comedy is that you get to keep all the money yourself. Audiences generally aren't willing to pay double the ticket price just because there are two people on stage, so all else being equal, a solo comedian will make more money than a double act.

Of course, if audiences like you much better in a double act, then you can overcome this disadvantage by getting better gigs than you would have done on your own (bigger venues, TV, movies etc.)

Comment: ...and if course this is more true for a comedian on the stand-up comedy club circuit trying to live on either x% of ticket sales or a venue's payment per time slot, compared to a comedian performing in a TV comedy show where their pay is one per-person negotiated up-front cost among many like paying the production crew etc, so solo shows are less likely to pay better. There's also more per-person costs for a touring show (same reason theatre troupes have fewer actors, with some playing multiple roles to keep the group smaller)